Error when converting GUI to a standalone executable using pyinstaller
I get a lot of error messages when I run the code pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --clean Todo_gui.py and an empty dist folder
Typed out below are the full error messages I get when I run the code
72007 WARNING: Execution of 'remove_all_resources' failed on attempt #1 / 20:       error(110, 'EndUpdateResourceW', 'The system cannot open the device or file specified.'). Retrying in 0.05 second(s)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 36, in pywin32error
yield
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 209, in BeginUpdateResource
return _resource._BeginUpdateResource(filename, delete)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 39, in check_null
raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
File    "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 231, in _console_script_run
run()
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 215, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 70, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1252, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1192, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\Todo_gui.spec", line 19, in <module>
exe = EXE(
      ^^^^
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 658, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 208, in BeginUpdateResource
with _pywin32error():
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(value)
File "C:\Users\käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Todo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 40, in pywin32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResourceW', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

I am currently learning python and I built a todo app GUI from a tutorial on a course and tried to turn it into a standalone executable using pyinstaller but I get different errors and it also gives me an empty dist folder. I expected to have a standalone executable app in the dist folder. Below is the code I tried in the pycharm terminal which returns the error
 pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --clean Todo_gui.py

Below is the full code for the todo app GUI
import Functions
import FreeSimpleGUI as sg
import time
import os

if not os.path.exists("todo.txt"):
    with open("todo.txt", "w") as file:
        pass

sg.theme("GreenMono")

clock = sg.Text("", key="clock")
label = sg.Text("Type in a todo")
input_box = sg.InputText(tooltip="Enter todo", key="todo")
add_button = sg.Button("Add")
list_box = sg.Listbox(values=Functions.get_todos(), key="todos",
                      enable_events=True, size=[45, 10])
edit_button = sg.Button("Edit")
complete_button = sg.Button("Complete")
exit_button = sg.Button("Exit")

window = sg.Window("My todo App",
                   layout=[[clock],
                       [label],
                       [input_box, add_button],
                       [list_box, edit_button, complete_button],
                       [exit_button]],
                   font=("Times New Roman", 18))

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=200)
    window["clock"].update(value=time.strftime("%B %D, %Y %H:%M:%S"))
    match event:
        case "Add":
            todos = Functions.get_todos()
            new_todo = values["todo"] + "\n"
            todos.append(new_todo)
            Functions.write_todos(todos)
            window["todos"].update(values=todos)

        case "Edit":
            try:
                todo_to_edit = values["todos"][0]
                new_todo = values["todo"]

                todos = Functions.get_todos()
                index = todos.index(todo_to_edit)
                todos[index] = new_todo
                Functions.write_todos(todos)
                window["todos"].update(values=todos)
            except IndexError:
                sg.popup("You need to select an item", font=("Times New Roman", 18))

        case "Complete":
            try:
                todo_to_complete = values["todos"][0]
                todos = Functions.get_todos()
                todos.remove(todo_to_complete)
                Functions.write_todos(todos)
                window["todos"].update(values=todos)
                window["todo"].update(value="")
            except IndexError:
                sg.popup("You need to select an item", font=("Times New Roman", 18))

        case "Exit":
            break
        case "todos":
            window["todo"].update(value=values["todos"][0])
        case sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break


window.close()


Below is the full code for my functions.py file

FILEPATH = "todo.txt"


def get_todos(filepath=FILEPATH):
    """ Read a text file and return the list of
        to-do items.
    """
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_local:
        todos_local = file_local.readlines()
        return todos_local


def write_todos(todos_arg, filepath=FILEPATH):
    """ Write the to-do items list in the text file."""
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(todos_arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
    print(get_todos())

 


Please look at this answer for details on how to correctly handle paths when using pyinstaller.

I couldn't reproduce your problem using pyinstaller 6.10.0 and python 3.12.7
